# What is this icon with a square border containing lines that look like text?

Tags: volume-control, samsung-one-ui

When I use the volume keys on my Samsung Z Flip4 I get the volume bar for media/ringtone volume. When I tap on **...**  I get the following advanced volume settings menu:

[image]

What is the purpose of the small icon (marked red) on the top left? If I tap on it its gets strikethrough. Another tap reverses that, and so on. Seems like a toggle button for something but I cannot figure out its purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems rather odd placement of a functionality in Volume panel, not to mention it causes a very bad user experience since the icon is not intuitive enough to be self-explanatory, nor does it explicitly instructs about itself to the user. Even the user manual from Samsung doesn't mention anything about this icon.

That little icon is for toggling *Live Caption*. Dallas Thomas of Gadget Hacks has dedicated a whole [article for Live Caption](https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/have-you-pressed-little-button-your-galaxys-volume-panel-yet-0384518/). That article showed up in Google Images search for the query "*samsung one ui volume panel*".

Comment: In deed, not intuitive at all. And not related to anything I would consider as "volume setting"

Comment: @wernfried-domscheit I disagree, it's perfectly placed for someone who is hearing impaired